# div contenteditable горизонтальная прокрутка выделением

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла необходимость сделать имитацию input[type=text] с помощью div contenteditable. Вроде сделал, вот только полной имитации не получилось. Если контента слишком много, текст скрывается по краям, а горизонтальная прокрутка выделением влево-вправо не работает. Работает только стрелочками. Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое / полуготовое решение для решения проблемы?